# OpenGL and threading

Tags: multithreading, opengl, sdl

It's known that OpenGL drivers usually don't tolerate [multi]threading.
However, does one have to deal with the main thread (of e.g. SDL) that
brought up a GL context? If one spawns a thread and from then on only
from there dispatches OpenGL commands will it be safe? Or does it have
to be restricted to the main thread that brought up the GL
context?

Comment: I don't see OpenGL being able to distinguish among threads and choosing [only] the one that created the context, but with today's crazy HW-accelerating drivers, who knows? Edit: Err, people who are about to answer below, obviously.

Comment: @aib: it's actually fairly easy to understand how it works: The context is usually stored in thread-local storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the OpenGL context current on the thread you want to use it, and a context can be made current only on one thread at a time. So creating a context and using it from another thread is fine if you make it current.

For multiple threads using OpenGL, you need multiple OpenGL contexts, one for each thread. And you can share resources between OpenGL contexts.

Comment: Now I wonder if SDL is able to do that. [For the time being I had the GL context started by the thread in question] [It crashed otherwise, not surprisingly]